# How to make books stand upright?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In Skyrim books can be placed on shelves by simply adding them as one would to a chest. They then arrange themselves on the shelf and are supposed to stand upright, nicely arranged. However, they often tend to fall down the moment they are placed. Is there any way to make them stand upright and stay that way?

Comment: Fill the bookshelf, so the books can't fall? I've never managed to fill a bookshelf entirely, so I don't know if it's possible.

Comment: Same here. I tried to fill the bookshelf but it's never entirely full.

Comment: I have had nothing but issues and bugs with bookshelves and books. Could be my Xbox, but they could be placed "in" the shelf. But would then disappear for ever.

Comment: Fill the bookcase with letters and notes, that's always fun to watch.  For mor of an answer to your question, bigger books have an easier time standing up, even when little books fall on them.

Comment: The USKP notably replaces the bookshelf scripts to fix a number of misbehaviours—if you don't have it, on PC it is worth installing that as a first step before more drastic measures.

Comment: I tried @SevenSidedDie 's suggestion. It's a great idea, and the books do seem a _bit_ more stable now, but they still tend to fall over whenever the shelf isn't completely fool. I am guessing that if a mod were to be made for this it would have to change the physics of the books rather than just the placement script.

Answer (score 3):

From my experience, simply filling the shelf until it's full of books will remedy the issue. Each time you add/remove books the physics are refreshed, so if you fill it up sometime later, they will all become standing. Even missing one book below the maximum for the shelf will allow the books to fall.

Comment: I tried this - I filled the shelf entirely with books so that no further books may be added (the game will not allow more books). They still fall over. I think the issue is that not all books are of the same thickness, and if you have some books that are thinner than the maximum thickness used in the game's book arranging code, there will be some space left at the end and the books will fall over.

Answer (score 0):

You could try manipulating them in such a way that they lean in one direction for support, where ever you hold the 'pick up' button on an object will be the center of manipulation, so try and fiddle with that a bit

Comment: I'm talking about the automatic arrangement of books. I'm not masochistic enough to try with the pick up button :).

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you don't fill the shelf up, or when you place notes along with books. The shelves fill from one direction to the other (Right to left), so theoretically you could place something on one side of the shelf, or multiple things, depending on how few book you are placing on the shelf. Place some armor, or something that will not move much when books are placed against it, on one side of the shelf, then place your books. I will test this and report on it later.

Comment: I recall left to right, but it's possible that it depends on the specific shelf.

Comment: You are correct, and I am changing my answer to suit.

Answer (score 0):

Put the big books some on the right some on the left and put letters and etc in the middle and they wont fall